# Linq Date Performance Death

Tags: c#, linq, performance, datetime

I have a database that stores dates broken into int's. I.e. Day, Month and Year are stored separately in different columns.

In existing SQL queries, the method used is:

DATEADD(dd, - 1, DATEADD(mm, Z.LastMonth, DATEADD(yy, Z.LastYear - 1900, 0))) AS last_date

I cannot change the database to store dates instead.

Looking further into the dateadd() function, it's converting from an integer (0).
Linq to SQL does not have a similar functionality i.e. Convert.ToDateTime(0). That results in an InvalidCastException.

I have tried concatenating strings to create a date, but it is WAYYYYY tooooo sllloowww. the time difference was about 10 minutes.

What else can I do? I don't particularly want to start mixing in SQL queries into the project either.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not storing the information as a date in the first place?

Comment: I don't believe so. But I can't change it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just write:

```
table.Select(z => new DateTime(z.LastYear, z.LastMonth, z.LastDay));
```

---

Alright, I tested this in Linqpad and it seems that Linq to SQL does decide to generate some weird character-conversion query.  I'm not entirely convinced that this is the source of the perf issue, but you can force a projection like this:

```
var dates = 
    (from z in table
     select new { Year = z.LastYear, Month = z.LastMonth, Day = z.LastDay })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(d => new 
        {
            Date = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day),
            NextDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)
        });
```

This will also get you the last day of the next month.

If you're really seeing such a huge performance, difference, though, I would venture a guess that you're looking in the wrong place, and that there's something else that's different.  90% of all database-related performance problems are due to poor or nonexistent indexing or non-sargable queries.

Comment: hey, thats an idea... why didn't I think of that! Thanks

Comment: That works much faster than concatenating strings. I think it feels slower than the dateadd() function. It will do for now. Thanks again mate.

Comment: @Mike: Don't go by feeling, profile it!  I find it hard to imagine such a simple projection being significantly slower than a slew of date operations in SQL.

Comment: I had left one of the sql queries I was working on, uncommented, and that is what I was looking at my debug window.

Looking further into it, it's rendering the same SQL as concatenating strings. So, this made no difference.

Comment: I need to get the last day of the next month as well, so I am doing:

    new DateTime(z.LastYear, z.LastMonth, z.LastDay).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); 

which is outputting some mega-ultra SQL, which is also taking its time.

DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p17 * 86400000)) % 86400000, DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p17 * 86400000)) / 86400000, DATEADD(MONTH, @p18, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NCHAR(2), [Z].[LastMonth]) + ('/' + (CONVERT(NCHAR(2), @p19) + ('/' + CONVERT(NCHAR(4), [Z].[LastYear])))), 101))))

Answer (score 3):

You could have linq to sql map to a custom sql statement or stored procedure to get the same sql performance.

Comment: I would go for a view or a SP too. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can map the function to make it usable in LINQ-TO-SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546175.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a view to the database? If you can, you can just define a view that looks just like your table, except with a real date, since it's backed by your turn-those-crazy-columns-into-a-date query. Then just query that with LINQ. I don't remember if SQL Server has smart view caching, but if so, it might actually perform better than your direct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

On the performance side of things, I presume that this date is your primary filtering criteria (the one that you expect to be indexed).

If that is the case:

- Make sure the column order in the index is Year, Month, Day.
- Do not send Date criteria into the data base as DateTimes, instead send integers in.  If you convert the table columns into a date before filtering, the index is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Much faster than concatenating strings is creating a character array and setting the elements of the character array yourself.  This is most practical if you can control at compile time the size of the strings.